# Gdk-ERROR in Python gui with Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, gtk, chat

It is my first post, so if I am doing something wrong please be patient.
I am working on a very simple chat program written in python with a gtk interface, a user has the server and the other has the client. All is working, except that I cannot send or receive messages (although the connection is established). I have already looked for a solution in the forum but I did not find anything. 
(Part of) the code for the GUI is:

```
gi.require_version ('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject, GLib
class GUI:
    def __init__ (self, is_server):
        GObject.threads_init ()
        [...]
        self.buffer1 = Gtk.TextBuffer ()
        self.text_box = Gtk.TextView (buffer=self.buffer1)
        self.text_box.set_editable (False)
        [...]
        self.th = threading.Thread (target = self.receive)
        self.th.daemon = True
        self.th.start ()
        Gtk.main ()
    def receive (self):
        while (True):
            try:
                msg = self.socket.receive_message ()
                if (msg != ""): self.insert_text (msg)
            except: pass
    def insert_text (self, text):
        self.text_box.set_editable (True)
        end_iter = self.buffer1.get_end_iter ()
        try: self.buffer1.insert (end_iter, text + "\n")
        except: pass
        self.text_box.set_editable (False)
        adj = self.scr.get_vadjustment ()
        adj.set_value (adj.get_upper ())
```

And in Client.py or Server.py (are the same lines):

```
class Client/Server:
    [...]
    def receive_message (self):
        try:
            msg0 = self.conn.recv (1024)
            msg = msg0.decode ("utf-8")
            return msg
        except: pass
```

The error I receive is:

```
(Chat.py:61330): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'Chat.py' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)'.
   (Details: rerial 892 error_code 1 request_code 0 (core protocol) minor_code 0)
   (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
    that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
    To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
    variable to change this behavior. You can get a meaningful
    backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Trace/BPT trap (code dumped)
```

I think it is a multithreading error because in the second thread I try to change the text of the Gtk.TextView but I am not sure (I am quite new with multithreading).

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call GTK+ functions from a thread other than the one that called `Gtk.main()`. You must change your threads to send data to the main thread and have that modify the GUI instead, for instance by wrapping the call to `insert_text()` in `receive()` in a `GLib.idle_add()`.